# I am creating a password generator and I need to retrieve the first half of the first and last name. But I need to round, assuming the name is odd

Tags: java

I know I should use ceil and floor methods but how would I implement those into my substrings?

````
        String password = "";

        password = firstName.substring(0, firstName.length() / 2) +
                lastName.substring(0,(lastName.length() / 2)); ```
````

Answer (score 0):

What you have should suffice. Let's say you have the following:

```java
String firstName = "Grifs";
System.out.println(lastName.length());     // 5
System.out.println(lastName.length() / 2); // 2
```

Dividing an odd integer by two will round down.

Or if you wanted to round up rather than the default rounding down you could do:

```
System.out.println((int)Math.ceil((double)lastName.length()/2)); // 3
```

or even dividing by 2.0 rather than 2 (Dropping the casting to double):

```
System.out.println((int)Math.ceil(lastName.length()/2.0)); // 3
```

Comment: Thank you, but for the first name if it automatically rounds down that's great, but then I would need to take half of the last name and round up.

Comment: I've updated my answer @G90

Comment: Appreciate it Luke!

Comment: One more question @Luke Garrigan So I just realized for the last name I need to retrieve the 2nd half of it. What would that change?

Comment: So if you just wanted the second half of the `lastName` the substring would need to start from the middle and end on the last character. So `string secondHalf = lastName.substring(lastName.length() / 2, lastName.length())` which would be "ifs" in the example above. And you'd substitute `lastName.length() / 2` with the code for rounding (in the answer I provided) if you wanted to exclude the middle letter and round up, which would be "fs". @G90

Comment: I seem to be getting the error saying that it cannot resolve symbol "secondHalf"

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in my reply, try: `String secondHalf = lastName.substring(lastName.length() / 2, lastName.length());`

Comment: The String secondHalf function does not work for me it just says it cant resolve the symbol.

Comment: Nevermind I got it to work, Thanks!